# Cannot find module 'internal/errors' Ionic 1.7.16 (ionic build)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build

I'm experiencing an issue while executing `ionic build ios` in an existing Ionic 1 project. It suddenly stopped working. Maybe since recent upgrade to new MacOS High Sierra or node.js version 8.6.0?

Re-installing node/ionic did not change anything:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:36:16
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)

Cannot find module 'internal/errors' (CLI v1.7.16)
```

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: Mac OS X High Sierra
Node Version: v8.6.0
NPM Version: 5.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Has someone any ideas on this?

Similar topic: [Cannot find module 'internal/errors' ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296140/cannot-find-module-internal-errors-ionic/46581657?noredirect=1#comment80119423_46581657)

Comment: UPDATE: It works if I downgrade to node v6.11.4 again. Seems to be an issue with node v8. Does someone still has an idea on how to get it running with node 8.6.0? I'm depending on newer version in other projects so I constantly need to switch node versions when working on other topics.... :-/

Comment: Yes upgrade the ionic-cli to the newest version (`3.12.0`).  `1.7.16` is over a year old.

Comment: You are right! I should also upgrade the ionic-cli, but I'm not sure if it is downwardly compatible to build v1 projects. Will give it a try! Thx!

Comment: How can I update the Ionic-cli today. Working on a old project